# Writing pipenv to zsh home

Tags: macos, zsh, pipenv

I wiped my MacBook Pro and installed Catalina 10.15.3.  The shell is now zsh, and after installing pipenv via the command `pip3 install pipenv`, I tried to run python 3.7 with the command `pipenv run python3 App.py` I am receiving the error `zsh: command not found`.

I have googled how to add the pipenv path to a .zprofile, but haven't been successful.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall pipenv (if you have already installed it):

```
pip3 uninstall pipenv
```

Then re-install it with brew (you should have brew installed first):

```
brew install pipenv
```

For Mac, it worked for me and might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion, please always post the complete error message. It is likely not just `zsh: command not found`, but `zsh: command not found: pipenv`. Then verify your PATH, whether it contains the directory of the command in question. Finally, `.zprofile` is sourced only for login shells. After your changes to `.zprofile`, create a new login shell by typing `zsh --login` to see your changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  I appreciate you helping to understand how to better write my questions as well.